# Working with Javascript to have table data display a description below the table

Tags: javascript, html-table

I want to have a description display in a `div` below the table when a viewer clicks on table data. This seems to work fine in Dreamweaver and in IE but isn't working in Firefox or Chrome.

The script:

```
<script>
    function changeDiv() {
        var txt = "This is some text";
        document.getElementById("textArea").textContent = txt;
    }
</script>
```

The table data:

```
 <td onClick="changeDiv()" class="amHours";>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong and how to get this working?

Comment: What is is supposed to do? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: That all looks fine to me; can you set up an example on jsfiddle.net that shows it not working?

Comment: So sorry, my question got cut off.  I'm hoping to display a description below a table when a viewer clicks on the table data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :)

```
document.getElementById('textArea').innerHTML = txt;
```

JsFiddle is seeming to have some issues, used wc3schools to test.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get the id "textArea" and the td element doesn't have an id at all, replace your td with this code(note: it adds an id "textArea"):

```
<td onClick="changeDiv()" id="textArea" class="amHours";>
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear, but those are some of the areas of my page that I'm working on. There's an empty div with the id="textArea" below the table that I'd like the text to display in onClick.

Comment: @SDERST if that code was relevant to the answer, why didn't you post it -.- Please post ALL of your code.

Comment: Sorry, new to site and thought an empty div would be irrelevant.

Comment: @SDERST it's not irrelevant at all, the javascript that you have posted works with it. I need to see everything.

Answer (score 0):

try  this

```
   document.getElementById("textArea").html= txt;
```